# Camera Permission on SwiftUI- Xcode 14.2

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-permissions, ios-privacy-settings

I have created a SwiftUI project. I need to add privacy for camera permission in info.plist file. But in my project there is no info.plist available. How do I achieve camera permission on it?

Here is my project Screenshot,

[image]

Comment: Click on PROJECT(Blue color Top Icon [Barcode_Scanner]), There you will see info, and that’s the info.plist

Comment: Wow! Yes..

So there is no need of info.plist?

Answer (score 3):

You can always find plist file by clicking the marked section on the picture. (whether it is a SwiftUI project or UIKit project)

**Screenshot of project file**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The critical, utterly undocumented other information one needs to proceed here is: there is no "plus" icon. You need to right click on ANY of the existing rows and click "ADD".

Answer (score 2):

Do the following to find the info.plist to add the necessary keys for the **privacy** of **camera permission** in your SwiftUI project.

At first click on the **Barcode_Scanner**
[image]

Now, Under the <kbd>TARGETS</kbd> click on your app and then click on <kbd>Info</kbd>.

[image]

You should be able to achieve now what you wanted to. Thanks!